# How to remove duplicates in a list of lists by reduce in Python

Tags: python

I just want to know whether if I can use reduce to remove duplicates in list of lists or not?

To be more specific, I want to write a reduce() function by using lambda here to remove duplicates in list of lists, for example, [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4]] -> [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4]].

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I'm sure you can. Whether or not the resulting code would be pythonic is a different question.

Comment: @SharonTan That was my answer and I deleted it because it got downvoted and I missed part of your question (the list of lists part). It was something along the lines of `reduce(lambda lst, val: lst if val in lst else lst + [val], [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5], [])`. :)

Comment: @MSeifert Thx! Yeah. I just want to reply you with the list of lists part. I think  there should be someway to do this to list of lists but I fail to do this.

Comment: @SharonTan You can update your question using my approach including what doesn't work. Then this would be a perfectly valid question that would probably also satisfy TigerhawkT3 :)

Comment: @MSeifert I just use something similar to yours and seems work.>>> c = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2,3,4], [2,3,4]]
>>> reduce(lambda lst, val: lst + [val] if val not in lst else lst + [], c, [])

Comment: post your code and also your example of input and output would be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just work out a way on @MSeifert 's sample code.
    reduce(lambda lst, val: lst + [val] if val not in lst else lst + [], input, [])
where input is the list of lists.